# How to execute Java program from parent directory

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction, classpath

I have a directory structure like this:

```
./
 +-- myClass
 |   +-- MainClass.class
 |
 +-- dummy
     +-- DummyClass.class
```

MainClass contains the `public static void main(String args[])` and imports dummy.DummyClass.

I compile with a simple command like `javac myClass/MainClass.java dummy/DummyClass.java` and all is fine. But when I try to execute it from ./ using `java myClass.MainClass` I get the "cannot find main class" error.

If I change the classpath with the -cp option then MainClass can't find DummyClass anymore.

Any hints?

Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `MainClass` have this at the top: `package myClass;`?

This is necessary for the class to considered part of the package `myClass` and only then it can be correctly addressed as `myClass.MainClass` - the directory structure has to mirror the pacakge structure.

Comment: ok, I'm stupid :D forgot to write it in the MainClass. Thank you, man ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

MainClass:

package myClass;

import dummy.Dummy;

public class MainClass{

java 
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
    System.out.println(:"This is the main class");
    Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
    dummy.exec();
}
```

}

Dummy:

package dummy;

public class Dummy{

```
public void exec(){

    System.out.println("This is the dummy class exec invocation");

}
```

}

At the commandline in the root folder:

javac myClass/MainClass.java dummy/Dummy.java

- This will result in the class being compiled

And, this will execute and invoke the "main" in the MainClass:
javac myClass/MainClass.java dummy/Dummy.java